# Why is this ODE classified as non-autonomous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my textbook, the following

$$\frac{d^2{x}}{d{t^2}}-\alpha x\frac{d{x}}{d{t}}-x+x^3=\sin (\omega t) $$

is given as an example of a non-autonomous ODE, without explanation. From my understanding, an ODE is non-autonomous when the coefficient of the dependent variable and its derivatives depend on the independent variable. In this case does $1$ count as a derivative of the dependent variable and therefore it is being multiplied by $\sin (\omega t)$?

Comment: Write in state space. You obtain something like $\dot \eta = f (\eta, t)$, which is a non-autonomous ODE.

Answer (score 3):

A differential equation is called *autonomous* if it can be written as
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x).
$$

In other words, the RHS cannot depend on $t$ explicitly, but only through dependence on $x(t)$.

In your case, you have a $\sin(\omega t)$ term on the RHS, so having this form is not possible.

Here are examples of autonomous ODEs:
$$
\begin{split}
x'(t) &= \sin\left(x(t)^2\right) + e^{x(t)}\\
x''(t) - 3x'(t) &= \cos(3x(t) + 35)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: @LutzL thanks, corrected, made it explicit and provided more examples.